# How many assertions can take place for a scenario

Tags: appium, bdd, cucumber-jvm, assertion

Am writing a sceanarios to verify a card in mobile app in BDD. The card contains 7 elements in it and each has a value or a copy. These need to be verified with predefined values / calculated values. so wanted to know, can i write the Assertions for all the 7 elements in single scenario or split it with 2/3 ?

Answer (score 2):

There are no much details, so I can't be specific with the answer. Let's say you are using Python client for Appium tests. In such case **it would be nice to use some unit testing framework** (it could be Python built-in unittest module).

I'll recommend you to **verify each element in a separate test case**. This approach will make your life easier - you'll get separate status for each element verification.

Speaking about *"How many assertions can take place for a scenario"* question - I believe **it depends on tools your are using**. With Python unittest **you may have a lot of assertions in a single test case, but this is bad practise**. Please read the following:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

If I knew what you were meaning by "card", this would be a help, but lets assume for this that it's a debit/credit card.

What we could do here, is simply have one assertion:

```
Scenario: Adding a new payment method
 Given I have a card with the following details:
  | Name            | Mr Test McTestington |
  | Card Number     | 4567 8901 2345 6789  |
  | Card Type       | Credit               |
  | Issuer          | MasterCard           |
  | Valid From Date | 01/23                |
  | Expiry Date     | 12/34                |
  | Security Code   | 123                  |

  And the card details are valid
 When I add the card as a new payment method
 Then I should be able to checkout the items in my basket with the card
  And I should see the order confirmation screen
```

Inside the `And the card details are valid` step, you would have the validation code for all of the items. This may involve breaking down each of these into functions that can be used elsewhere:

```
public boolean validName(string name){
    bool valid = false;
    // validate name - set valid to true if it meets validation criteria
    return valid;
}
```

As an example (Java is not my strong point, but this is just an outline on my suggestion).

In essence, making it readable is what cucumber does best, to describe functionality in language that the Development Team and the Business have agreed on, so that everyone can understand exactly what is being described in your Scenario. It's more about conversations than testing things.

Is it like I have done in my example, where you don't necessarily need to validate each card detail individually?

It all comes down to a judgement call.

And if it does come down to this judgement call, where you believe each thing needs to be validated individually, why not use a Scenario Outline to help you out?

```
Scenario Outline: Valid card details
 Given I have a card with the "<detail>" of "<value>"
 Then the card detail "<detail>" should be valid

Examples:
  | detail          | value                |
  | Name            | Mr Test McTestington |
  | Card Number     | 4567 8901 2345 6789  |
  | Card Type       | Credit               |
  | Issuer          | MasterCard           |
  | Valid From Date | 01/23                |
  | Expiry Date     | 12/34                |
  | Security Code   | 123                  |
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, But doesn't it feel loads of assertions in one scenario

Comment: It may feel like that, but sometimes it does make sense. There doesn't always have to be only one outcome to a single scenario. If it makes sense to both you and the business, you're doing it right